# TabBar height is not the same with ActionBar (Sherlock) height in Android 4.1 (Galaxy Nexus)

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-tabs

As the title says, for some strange reason, the height of the TabBar does not follow the height of the ActionBar, cutting the tabs.

I am using ActionBar Sherlock, I've tested in many devices and the problem is present only in my Galaxy Nexus running Android 4.1.
Also, I've tried in landscape, where the tabs integrate with the ActionBar and there is no problem at all there, so the problem is the height of the TabBar.

Thanks!

Comment: can you attach a screenshot?

Comment: Yes, you can find the screenshot here: http://cl.ly/image/3Y1o132c2k27. The upper black square is the ActionBar, I've made it extra bit to spot the difference.